# Reinstall wordpress from ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, uninstallation

I wanted to reinstall wordpress because it gave so many errors, so I tried this:
*rm -r /etc/wordpress, 
rm -r /usr/share/wordpress,
rm -r /var/lib/wordpress*

Also I did this to remove the symbolic link:
unlink /var/www/html/wordpress

Now I want to install a new one using this:
*apt-get install wordpress*, but it give me this message:
*wordpress is already the newest version, 0 updgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded*

After that I check the directories but wordpress is not appearing

What can I do?

Comment: If you installed the package with `apt-get` you should remove it with `apt-get` using `apt-get remove <package>`

Comment: isn't this more appropriate on server fault?

Comment: It works dude, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$ sudo apt-get remove wordpress
$ sudo apt-get purge wordpress
```

Found it here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1284438